# Perform a task for every object in an array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array in JavaScript, I would like the code to display each of the items in the array in an h1 element. How do I do this?

This is my idea so far:

```js
names = ["Jeff", "Steve", "Bill"];

function show() {
  let card = document.createElement('div');
  card.innerHTML = '<h1>${names}</h1>';
  document.body.appendChild(card);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="show()">Click to show</button>
```

How do i have it so that each h1 element represents each value of the names array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.forEach()`:

```js
const names = ["Jeff", "Steve", "Bill"];

function show() {
  let card = document.createElement('div');
  names.forEach(name => {
    card.innerHTML += `<h1>${name}</h1>`
  });
  document.body.appendChild(card);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="show()">Click to show</button>
```

Comment: @VedTiwari There are other ways too, but basically you need to iterate over the array. Do accept if the answer helped you